# How Do I wrap only selected elements in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In a badly designed `table` like this:

```
<table id="bow-me">
    <td class="show-me">Pet is Great</td>
    <td class="show-me">Pete is Greate</td>

    <td class="go-me">Met is Great</td>
    <td class="go-me">Mete is Greate</td>

    <td class="show-me">Latte is Great</td>
    <td class="show-me">Lattus is Greate</td>

    <td class="low-me">Bet is Great</td>
    <td class="low-me">Bette is Greate</td>

    <td class="go-me">Rat is Great</td>
    <td class="go-me">Rate is Greate</td>
</table>
```

I need to add the `<tr>` tag after every 2 `<td>` tags using jQuery. To make things clear, I have separated 2 `<td>`s in above question.

At first I did:

```
$('.show-me').wrapAll('<tr class="know-me"> </tr>');
$('.go-me').wrapAll('<tr class="know-me"> </tr>');
$('.low-me').wrapAll('<tr class="know-me"> </tr>');
```

But the messes up the structure.

Then I tried `wrap('<tr></tr>')`, which wraps every `td` with `tr`.

I also tried with `before()` and `after()` methods, but wasn't successful with it too.

My ideal output should be:

```
<table id="bow-me">
    <tr class="know-me">
        <td class="show-me">Pet is Great</td>
        <td class="show-me">Pete is Greate</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="know-me">
        <td class="go-me">Met is Great</td>
        <td class="go-me">Mete is Greate</td>
    </tr>    
    <tr class="know-me">
        <td class="show-me">Latte is Great</td>
        <td class="show-me">Lattus is Greate</td>
    </tr> 
    <tr class="know-me">
        <td class="low-me">Bet is Great</td>
        <td class="low-me">Bette is Greate</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="know-me">
        <td class="go-me">Rat is Great</td>
        <td class="go-me">Rate is Greate</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Is there anyway I can do this with jQuery?

**[The JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WNQ3d/1/)**

Comment: you can take both td in var using each loop and clone it in tr after that append it to table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML (the original source code) is not the same as the DOM (the page as your browser and jQuery understand it). When your browser reads the original HTML, it considers it invalid and automatically adds `<tr>` tags around all the table cells.

You ought to alter your original HTML, or else use `div` elements and CSS to add `display: table-cell` as needed. HTML:

```
<div id="bow-me">
    <div class="show-me">Pet is Great</div>
    <div class="show-me">Pete is Greate</div>

    <div class="go-me">Met is Great</div>
    <div class="go-me">Mete is Greate</div>

    <div class="show-me">Latte is Great</div>
    <div class="show-me">Lattus is Greate</div>

    <div class="low-me">Bet is Great</div>
    <div class="low-me">Bette is Greate</div>

    <div class="go-me">Rat is Great</div>
    <div class="go-me">Rate is Greate</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#bow-me {
    display: table;
}
.know-me {
    display: table-row;
}
.show-me, .go-me, .low-me {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

And now this slightly unorthodox jQuery will do what you want:

```
$('.show-me,.go-me,.low-me').each(function() {
    var klass = $(this).attr('class');
    if (!$(this).closest('.know-me').length) { // not already wrapped in a row
        $(this).nextUntil(':not(".'+klass+'")').addBack()
               .wrapAll('<div class="know-me">');
    };
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/QhKP7/

Answer (score 4):

You can do:

```
var tds = $('#bow-me td');
for (var i = 0; i < tds.length; i += 2) {
    tds.slice(i, i + 2).wrapAll('<tr class="know-me"></tr>');
}
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WNQ3d/2/)**

---

As @Blazemonger suggestion, you can use **[unwrap()](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/)** to remove the auto-generated `tr` here:

```
$('.know-me').unwrap();
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WNQ3d/7/)**

Comment: The browser auto-generates `tr` tags when the DOM is generated. Your fiddle has several `tr`s inside the original `tr`, which is invalid. You need to remove the original `tr` as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can wrap 2 dom nodes...

I suspect you will have to do something like:

```
$('#bow-me').find('td:nth-child(2n+1),td:nth-child(2n+2)').wrapAll('<tr class="know-me"></tr>');
```

Hope someone improves and finds a better way but for now thats all I got

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code;

```
var length = $("#bow-me td").length;

for (var i = 0; i <= length; i += 2) {
    $("#bow-me td:eq(" + i + "), #bow-me td:eq(" + (i+1) + ")").wrapAll('<tr class="know-me"></tr>');
}
```

Here is a working fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/cubuzoa/WNQ3d/4/**

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
var els = $('td'),
    trow;
for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) { 
    if (i%2 === 0) {
        trow = $('<tr class="know-me" />');
        $(els[i]).before(trow);
        trow.append(els[i]);
        trow.append(els[i + 1]);
    }
}
```

Code snippet:

```js
var els = $('td'),
  trow;
for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
  if (i % 2 === 0) {
    trow = $('<tr class="know-me" />');
    $(els[i]).before(trow);
    trow.append(els[i]);
    trow.append(els[i + 1]);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="bow-me">
  <td class="show-me">Pet is Great</td>
  <td class="show-me">Pete is Greate</td>

  <td class="go-me">Met is Great</td>
  <td class="go-me">Mete is Greate</td>

  <td class="show-me">Latte is Great</td>
  <td class="show-me">Lattus is Greate</td>

  <td class="low-me">Bet is Great</td>
  <td class="low-me">Bette is Greate</td>

  <td class="go-me">Rat is Great</td>
  <td class="go-me">Rate is Greate</td>
</table>
```